# lightswitch property does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have recently added a property to a entity. When I add that property to the screen I am getting an error saying
"The property 'ContactNumber' does not exist on type 'LightSwitchApplication.Order'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type"

I am sending out emails with data from that newly created property however when I run the screen it throws the error.

Comment: Are you referencing a property that doesn't exist in the entity code or in the screen code?

Comment: I added it as a new property on a table.

Comment: Did you update your DataSource to reflect the changes in the table?

Comment: if this is on the HTML Client, it sometimes requires you to include .contentItem aswell as .screen on the JavaScript file, if its in the brackets, use it :) for example contentItem.screen.Order.ContactNumber;